# '#' sign inside of html element

Tags: javascript, angular

I have found unknown to me singature

```
<input type="file" [multiple]="multiple" #fileInput>
<upload-drawing #fu (change)="fu.upload()" [multiple]="true"></upload-drawing>

export class DrawingUploadComponent
{

  @Input() multiple: boolean = false;
  @ViewChild('fileInput') inputEl: ElementRef;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  upload() {
    let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
    let fileCount: number = inputEl.files.length;
    let formData = new FormData();
    if (fileCount > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
        formData.append('file', inputEl.files.item(i));
      }
      this.http
        .post('http://localhost:8080/upload', formData).toPromise().then(() => console.log('success')).catch(() => console.log('error'));
    }
  }
}
```

Im confused with these '#' signs inside of  and  tags. What are they, what is the purpose of inserting them inside. I can see that is some kind of identifier because of `@ViewChild('fileInput')` is there more to it?

Comment: In simple words # is used to create a local varaible for the component

Answer (score 4):

These are [template reference variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html).

> A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element within a template. It can also be a reference to an Angular component or directive or a web component.

They allow different parts of your template to share data. A line like

```
<input type="file" [multiple]="multiple" #fileInput>
```

will create a `fileInput` variable to be consumed by other parts of your template or by your Angular component.

Answer (score 0):

In your ts you are accessing the input directly using ViewChild. It is basically like calling `document.getElementById` in javascript.
I used similar code when I dealt with files.